# Looking for a monster show but I only remember a few things from the two episodes I caught

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

I remember this show having this blond haired boy in a white sweater running down an alley way from something and then this Grim Reaper type thing swooped in to save this kid. And it was a regular occurrence that we would see this kid with this grim reaper like being.

I also remember that the title screens were black with red letters and there would be a heart beat incorporated into the screen somehow, whether it had been a sound or the title screen beating like a heart. I also seem to remember that it was after *Cybersix* if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this?  Any idea what channel it was on?

Comment: Possibly "Death Note"? This is a Japanese show about the spirit of death. I have never seen the show, but the images that I've seen could fit your description.

Comment: Was this on Télétoon?

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't match entirely, but could this be [Mighty Max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Max_(TV_series))?

Max is a blonde boy with a white sweater that bears a red initial M; the show ran from 1993 to 1994. His friends are a viking-like bodyguard and a birdlike humanoid rather than a grim reaper like thing, though.